# Issues Wordpress Template and SEO Yoast Meta Description

Tags: wordpress

Recently I've configured Yoast By SEO and a Wordpress Template to start a web blog. 
But, after configuring the template and the Plugin I found out that the meta description that google is considering.

For Home Page is: The Tagline option available in the General Settings
For Posts: Considering the initial lines of the articles not the meta box available by the Yoast Plugin.
Here is the Template [URL](http://themeforest.net/item/newscore-a-blog-magazine-and-news-theme-for-wp/7851846):

Please Help me out to fix this issue it is killing my CTR
[Website URL](http://www.ipadappsbuzz.com)

Comment: When I searched your site, I don't see that meta description. It says "Steps to Disable Apple Music from your iPad...". You know that just because you update the meta description, it doesn't automatically change in the search results? It takes time for Google and other engines to reindex your pages.

Comment: Usually SEO plugins override WP settings, so you'll have to set the description in the plugin options, even for the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

I seen in your site that the  tag for description is coming 2 times one from your theme's header file and one from yoast SEO plugin. First remove the meta tag if you see in your theme's header.php file. Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me how to achieve that

Comment: @P082 First check your currnet active theme's header.php, Is there any meta description tag you found?

Comment: No I didn't find anything on the Header.php

Comment: @P082 Have you seen your sites view source? There is 2 meta description is displayed for you or not. If yes then first you have to find it out that from where that another description is came.

Comment: @P082 Reply quickly, if you need help!

Comment: No it's not the same tag. `<meta content="" name="description" />` is used by search engines, `<meta property="og:description" name="" />` is an [OpenGraph tag](http://ogp.me/) which is used by some other applications (often socials one) like Facebook.

Comment: @vard Now its not showing, but when i commented at that time there is 2 meta description tag i seen. I'm talking about `<meta content="" name="description" />`.

Comment: @KaushaMehta Ok, OP probably fixed something in the mid-time.

Comment: I've asked one of my friend and he fixed this issue. Could you guys verify this from your end.
He told me that there is a conflict with the template SEO options and SEO by Yoast Features.

Comment: @P082 For me i think all good, becuase first its coming 2 meta description and now there is only one meta description tag.